# A good simple animation program for technical animations?

Tags: windows, drawing, animation

I am very good with Inkscape, the open source SVG drawing tool. I am looking for something similar in terms of animation - I'd like to do simple things like animate a circle growing, a ball falling, a square moving around, eventually a spline changing shape and the camera's zoom level changing, without the overhead of heavy programs like After Effects or Flash. Do you know of simple to use software that would let me do these sorts of animations, to be embedded in PowerPoint slides for example. Obviously I am not looking for an answer "use PowerPoint"! The program lets me animate moving a whole object, but not the object's properties like color, shape, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations SE!  Do you have an OS preference?  Are you looking for recommendations for gratis (freeware) or paid software?

Comment: Windows only. Freeware is preferred, but paid is OK too.

Comment: I am not sure if it meets your criteria, but Blender might work for you.  It does run on Windows and is even available as a portable app from Portableapps.com.  Portableapps also has K-3D which is labeled as animation software.  I have never tried K-3D, but have played with Blender a little.

Comment: Blender is for 3d modeling, game development, and/or video editing. Sure you can import and [export](http://goinkscape.com/use-blender-freestyle-to-export-svg-artwork/) an svg with Blender, but it's not very effective. Try [Animatron](https://www.animatron.com/)!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Synfig Studio](http://www.synfig.org/cms/) with [this plugin](http://wiki.synfig.org/Sif2svg), but the UI is horrible and takes awhile to learn which is why I wouldn't recommend it.

What I suggest is [Animatron](https://www.animatron.com/). Note, it's a web application, but you can turn it into a desktop app (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and/or Chrome) using [WebDGap](http://webdgap.sourceforge.net/) if needed.

What's nice about [Animatron](https://www.animatron.com/) is it's very similar to Adobe Flash or [Edge Animate](https://www.adobe.com/products/edge-animate.html) for creating your animations. You can download as...

- HTML5 Code
- PNG
- SVG
- SVG SMIL Animation
- Video
- GIF

It works with events as well, plus you can [add in your own audio too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDl4jobXqfA)!

There's also [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) too.